# Android Get SMS Code with the Service BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android

I have login which requests for the SMS Code to Login the user. I have created the Receiver Class to receive the SMS Code the service reads the Full SMS from the Sender and it prints in the Log. I just want the recevier to get the code and verifiy on its own just like whatsapp.

This is the SMS I receive :-

> Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your login code for App is :4132

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = SmsReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SMS_ORIGIN = "+1 904-414-3527";
    private static final String OTP_DELIMITER = ":";
    private Context context;
    private String code = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);
                    String senderAddress = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.e(TAG, "Received SMS: " + message + ", Sender: " + senderAddress);

                    // if the SMS is not from our gateway, ignore the message
                    if (!senderAddress.toLowerCase().contains(SMS_ORIGIN)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // verification code from sms
                    String verificationCode = getVerificationCode(message);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OTP received: " + verificationCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.e(TAG, "OTP received: " + verificationCode);

                   Intent hhtpIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                    hhtpIntent.putExtra("otp", verificationCode);
                    context.startService(hhtpIntent); 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting the OTP from sms message body
     * ':' is the separator of OTP from the message
     *
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {

        int index = message.indexOf(OTP_DELIMITER);

        if (index != -1) {
            int start = index + 2;
            int length = 4;
            code = message.substring(start, start + length);
        }
        return code;
    }
}
```

This where I want the code to be verified on its own with the intent but it doesn't work

```
 public void doLogin() {
       /* String otp = getIntent().getStringExtra("otp");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You must enter the 4 digit code texted to your phone number." + otp,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


            if (textField.getText().toString().length() != 4) {
                codeUI();
            } else {
                code = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().toString());
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                params.put("codeEntry", code);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("logIn", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                    public void done(String response, ParseException e) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (e == null) {
                            token = response;
                            Log.d("Cloud Response", "There were no exceptions! " + response);
                            ParseUser.becomeInBackground(token, new LogInCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        parseUser.isAuthenticated();
                                        Log.d("Cloud Response", "There were no exceptions! ");
                                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class);
                                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("Cloud Response", "Exception: " + e);
                                        TSnackbar snackbar = TSnackbar
                                                .make(relative,"Something went wrong:" + e,TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        snackbar.show();
                                        phoneNumberUI();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            codeUI();
                            Log.d("Cloud Response", "Exception: " + response + e);
                            TSnackbar snackbar = TSnackbar
                                    .make(relative,"Incorrect Code",TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
public String GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE = "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your login code for App is : (.*).";
SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];

Pattern generalCodePattern = Pattern.compile(GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE);
Matcher generalCodeMatcher = generalCodePattern .matcher(message[0]
                        .getMessageBody().toString());

if (generalCodeMatcher.find()) {
 String code= generalCodeMatcher.group(1);
   //Do Your  stuff here for Match your otp
 }
```

Comment: find() is `java.util.regex.Matcher` this package's method, and show updated comment

Comment: what was the problem now.?

Comment: No Error generated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112255/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-savita).

Comment: This code I already implemented in my project its working perfect.